Add a constant number to google sheets query result
I have data in two columns labeled Email and 01 respectively.
I want to use a query to rearrange the data so that there are 3 columns:

Columns 2 and 3 will contain the data from my original two columns if the second column  contained the word "cool"
Column 1 for each populated row will contain 01

Example Data

Source data is in columns B and C
desired result is in Columns E, F, G.


The three rows {B6:C7;B10:C10} are included in F6:G8 of the results because they all had "cool" in column C.
The 01 from C5 is repeated in Column E for each populated row in Columns F, G.





B
C
D
E
F
G




5
Email
01


Email



6
a
cool

01
a
cool


7
c
cool

01
c
cool


8
v
y

01
f
cool


9
g
x






10
f
cool







How can I perform a query like this?


={"","email","";QUERY(B6:C,"select '" & TRIM($C$5) &"', B, C where C='cool' label '" & TRIM($C$5) &"' ''",0)}

This formula will literally do what is shown in your screenshot.
Update For second screenshot no need QUERY():
={"","email","";ArrayFormula(SORT(SPLIT(FLATTEN(C5:E5&""&B6:B10&""&C6:E10),""),1,TRUE))}

Details see Unpivot In Google Sheets With Formulas
